# Fork refresh after salesforce sandbox refresh

Tags: salesforce

My client is using VSTS as a repository for salesforce code , and deployment tool as Copado continous integration
When i refresh the Salesforce sandbox , how the code will get updated in VSTS fork? Is there is any way that fork can be refesh?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for this are here: https://docs.copado.com/article/l78y5b9ntw-sandbox-refresh

1. Create a new branch out of the branch that is linked to the sandbox. This branch will be a backup branch to review any commit history in the future. You should add the current date in the name of the backup branch.
   E.g. If your sandbox branch is named dev1, then the name of the backup branch will be dev1_backup_MM/DD/YYYY.
2. Delete the branch linked to the sandbox (e.g. dev1).
3. If you are cloning your new sandbox out of production, create a new branch out of master and name it with the same name as the branch deleted in the previous step. If you're cloning your sandbox out of another sandbox, then create a new branch out of that parent sandbox's branch.